# Consulta simple en base de datos SQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql, base-de-datos, sqlite3

Tengo una tabla con tres datos: número de trabajador, empresa en la que trabaja y su salario. Pues bién, me piden que encuentre la empresa con más trabajadores.

De momento, he hecho esto:

```
select count(*), id_empresa from feina group by id_empresa;
```

Lo cual me devuelve cada empresa y el número de trabajadores que tiene, por aquí todo bien. Mi problema es que cuándo hago un max para devolver la que más trabajadores tenga, no sé muy bien cómo aplicarlo.

Si alguien me pudiera hechar una mano estaría agradecido (no sé apenas nada de SQL y estoy aprendiendo xd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select max(Total) as Maximo, id_empresa
from
(
 select count(*) as Total, id_empresa 
 from feina 
 group by id_empresa
)
```

Haces una **subconsulta** la cual sería la consulta que ya tienes hecha, pero se le da al campo que va a contar los totales de cada departamento (tu **count(*)**) el **alias de Total**. Sobre esta consulta harías entonces una **consulta general** la cual utilizando la **funcion Max** al **campo Total** vas a seleccionar el departamento que más trabajadores tiene.

Comment: Exacto... Mil gracias:)

Comment: @FAFernández si la respuesta te fue util te agradeceria q la marcaras como aceptada, gracias